# Squid proxy to bypass DNS restrictions

Tags: networking, firefox, dns, proxy

I wanted to host a proxy on one of my PC, and so I installed and configured Squid on it.

I want to use this proxy to bypass web URL filtering from another position.

I can reach my PC, but there is a problem:

After configuring Firefox to use my proxy (Options → Advanced → net → settings → Proxy HTTP) I've noticed that websites are still blocked, but if I go on something like whatismyip.com I see the IP of my PC that is hosting the proxy.

I've found out that requests go through the default dns first, that is the one who blocks some websites. I can NOT change it, because all others are blocked. 
To me it looks strange since i would expect the request to be fully sent to the proxy server, and should be up to the proxy to do the request to the dns.  Anyway is there a way to get around that?

TL,DR: I want to use Squid to bypass a dns url filtering

Comment: Is this squid machine outside the network behind the original proxy? If not, then the requests are likely blocked either by default (so people can't just by-pass the original proxy) or redirected to the original proxy.

You need to provide more description of what you've setup so it can be diagnosed correctly.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I'm in a VPN, the squid machine is outside (I've to use it at work, and it is hosted on my home PC)

Comment: On the squid machine itself, does the internet work etc?; Also are you using a socks proxy, http, etc?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly without any restrictions. HTTP.   I also tried glype and it works perfect but i don't want a web proxy to avoid problems with js, media, etc.  That's why i would like to make squid work